# Extract specific set lines matching a rule

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have a large file with the logs as shown below. There are about 30000 instance of such events logged. I need to extract those lines beginning with `RINGING` and `CLOSE` (included) and which does NOT contain `30 30`.

The requirement is :

Of the two instances seen below, I need only Instance 2 retained. Instance 1 needs to be deleted entirely (they form the large chunk of the file)

Instance 1:

```
313782 Aug 19 18:37:04.925: <DATA>  RINGING|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
313783 Aug 19 18:37:05.262: <DATA>  TRAINING|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
313784 Aug 19 18:37:09.028: <DATA>  OUT  |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|2 bytes  |30 93
313785 Aug 19 18:37:09.705: <DATA>  IN   |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|4 bytes  |30 73 F9 F8
313786 Aug 19 18:37:18.532: <DATA>  IN   |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|336 bytes  |30 10 60 00 06 00 00 6F 12 00                                                                                 ...
313787 Aug 19 18:37:19.485: <DATA>  OUT  |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|133 bytes  |30 30 60 00 00 00 06 6F 12 10                                                                                 ...
313788 Aug 19 18:37:20.898: <DATA>  TRAINING|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
313789 Aug 19 18:37:22.006: <DATA>  CLOSE|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
```

Instance 2:

(Line with 30 30 is not present)

```
313782 Aug 19 18:37:04.925: <DATA>  RINGING|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
313783 Aug 19 18:37:05.262: <DATA>  TRAINING|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
313784 Aug 19 18:37:09.028: <DATA>  OUT  |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|2 bytes  |30 93
313785 Aug 19 18:37:09.705: <DATA>  IN   |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|4 bytes  |30 73 F9 F8
313786 Aug 19 18:37:18.532: <DATA>  IN   |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|336 bytes  |30 10 60 00 06 00 00 6F 12 00                                                                                                                                                         ...
313788 Aug 19 18:37:20.898: <DATA>  TRAINING|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
313789 Aug 19 18:37:22.006: <DATA>  CLOSE|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your logfile is called `logfile`, here is an `awk` solution with the sample output:

```
$ awk '/RINGING/,/CLOSE/ {if (/30 30/){f=1}; a=a"\n"$0} f==0 && /CLOSE/ {print a} /CLOSE/{a="";f=0}' logfile    

313782 Aug 19 18:37:04.925: <DATA>  RINGING|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
313783 Aug 19 18:37:05.262: <DATA>  TRAINING|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
313784 Aug 19 18:37:09.028: <DATA>  OUT  |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|2 bytes  |30 93
313785 Aug 19 18:37:09.705: <DATA>  IN   |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|4 bytes  |30 73 F9 F8
313786 Aug 19 18:37:18.532: <DATA>  IN   |254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|336 bytes  |30 10 60 00 06 00 00 6F 12 00
313788 Aug 19 18:37:20.898: <DATA>  TRAINING|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
313789 Aug 19 18:37:22.006: <DATA>  CLOSE|254|01136097645|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
```

#### Explanation

Taking each `awk` command in turn:

- `/RINGING/,/CLOSE/ {if (/30 30/){f=1}; a=a"\n"$0}`

  The expression `/RINGING/,/CLOSE/` is a range: it specifies that this command only applies to groups of lines.  A group starts when a line is encountered that includes the text `RINGING`.  The group ends when a line including the text `CLOSE` is encountered.  For any line in such a group, the commands in braces are executed.  The first of these sets the flag `f` to one if the line contains `30 30`.  The second command appends the current line to the variable `a`.
- `f==0 && /CLOSE/ {print a}`

  The commands in braces here are preceded by two conditions and'd together.  The first condition specifies that the flag `f` is zero (meaning that `30 30` was not found in this group) and the second specifies that this line contain the text `CLOSE`.  If both those conditions are met, then the group of lines, stored in the `a` variable, are printed.
- `/CLOSE/{a="";f=0}`

  Lastly, on any line containing the text `CLOSE`, the variable `a` is reset to the empty string and the flag `f` is set to zero.  When this is done, the code is prepared to start on the next group of lines, should there be one.

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible using a perl compatible regex (PCRE) for example

```
pcregrep -M '^.*?RINGING(?(?!30 30)(?s).)+?CLOSE.*?$' file
```

or

```
grep -zPo '^.*?RINGING(?(?!30 30)(?s).)+?CLOSE.*?$' file
```

Alternatively, using GNU awk's more expressive record separator

```
gawk -vRS="CLOSE[^\n]*\n" -vORS= '!/30 30/ {print; print RT}' file
```

Comment: I have edited to the question to be more clear. My requirement is bit different.Thanks